# I will load data via API into my ListView async

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, api, listview

I will load data via API into my ListView async.

I have a list of items (1 to 6300) and in my search box I can search for the items and then it will be displayed in the ListView.

Now I want to show the items Avg prices, which come from a JSON Api.

If you want to take a look at the tool, here is the git link: https://github.com/Triky313/AlbionOnline-StatisticsAnalysis

My current method looks like this. Once new data is loaded from the API and then again only if they are older than one hour.

```
    public static ObservableCollection<MarketStatChartItem> MarketStatChartItemList = new ObservableCollection<MarketStatChartItem>();

    public static async Task<string> GetMarketStatAvgPriceAsync(string uniqueName, Location location)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                var apiString = "https://www.albion-online-data.com/api/v1/stats/charts/" +
                                $"{FormattingUniqueNameForApi(uniqueName)}?date={DateTime.Now:MM-dd-yyyy}";

                var itemCheck = MarketStatChartItemList?.FirstOrDefault(i => i.UniqueName == uniqueName);

                if (itemCheck == null)
                {
                    var itemString = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(apiString);
                    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MarketStatChartResponse>>(itemString);

                    var newItem = new MarketStatChartItem()
                    {
                        UniqueName = uniqueName,
                        MarketStatChartResponse = values,
                        LastUpdate = DateTime.Now
                    };

                    MarketStatChartItemList?.Add(newItem);

                    var data = newItem.MarketStatChartResponse
                        .FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.Location == Locations.GetName(location))?.Data;
                    var findIndex = data?.TimeStamps?.FindIndex(t => t == data.TimeStamps.Max());

                    if (findIndex != null)
                        return data.PricesAvg[(int) findIndex].ToString("N", LanguageController.DefaultCultureInfo);
                    return "-";
                }

                if (itemCheck.LastUpdate <= DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1))
                {
                    var itemString = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(apiString);
                    var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MarketStatChartResponse>>(itemString);

                    itemCheck.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
                    itemCheck.MarketStatChartResponse = values;
                }

                var itemCheckData = itemCheck.MarketStatChartResponse
                    .FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.Location == Locations.GetName(location))?.Data;
                var itemCheckFindIndex =
                    itemCheckData?.TimeStamps?.FindIndex(t => t == itemCheckData.TimeStamps.Max());

                if (itemCheckFindIndex != null)
                    return itemCheckData.PricesAvg[(int) itemCheckFindIndex]
                        .ToString("N", LanguageController.DefaultCultureInfo);
                return "-";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.StackTrace);
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            return "-";
        }
    }
```

Through the API requests everything loads very long and I can not normally use the search.

Does anyone know of a better solution for loading asnyc data without the search problems?

EDIT:
Here again visually represented...
[image]

The item list is already loaded and the search is very fast.

Now you can see some minuses on the right side, there should be numbers. These numbers are loaded later when the item is shown in the list.

The problem: The search is extremely stale if he has 50+ items in the search and then fill them with the data of the API.

For each item, an API request is made.

Can this API query be canceled if the search changes or is there another possibility?

Comment: You might want to also visually show us what you want. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here. Are you trying to pull all 6300 items first and then searching through the data once you have it? Are you passing a search into the API? Are you pulling the data every time you search? Please add more specifics.

Comment: @DavidBentley Thanks for your answer, I have expanded my question.